# Change CSS of Embedded Discord Website "Widget"

Tags: css, discord

I was easily able to determine how to embed Discord in to a website using an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=[__id__here_]&#38;theme=dark" style="height: 500px; margin: 2px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

How do I change the CSS for the chat "widget"?

Important: this question is for the *website*, *not* [individual users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024071/custom-css-code-for-discordapp).

Comment: As far as i know you can change the CSS for the iframe but not for the widget inside the iframe. You would probably need JavaScript.